# amazon SES on Google Cloud Computing instance VM using postfix

Tags: linux, unix, amazon-ec2, debian

can anyone help me configure postfix to use with amazon ses please.. 
i can successfully follow instructions here using sendgrid 
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail 
and it is working fine using sendgrid..

But i would like to adjust settings to use amazon SES instead of sendgrid, I am not even sure if that is possible seems google has blocked all smtp ports.

any help greatly appreciated...

I have tried these.. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html  but did not work 
running debian 7 google VM instance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

solved it already.. in case it helps others Google Instance VM can use port 2587. I unblocked that from my console, then used the popular phpmailer php  library to send mail...
now all is working perfectly..

finding the port was hard.. google documentation does not make that clear..

Comment: Can you please share the configuration you made? how come you used this port while SES uses port 25? I'm also trying to implement this same thing on my Compute engine.

Comment: Sorry I started using amazon ec2 instead of Google vm my account and my settings are gone. I would try the port 2587 as that is the only one I could get working but don't remember much else

Comment: Thanks anyway, its working now, it was hard to find all the needed info to make it work, so I posted another answer for anyone facing the same troubles as I did.

Answer (score 8):

I finally got it to work too, and as per to the comments in the answer, I will provide how I did it step by step.

Amazon uses the mentioned port in the answer, and this is mentioned here, under STARTTLS:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html#smtp-connect-secure-tunnel

I have an already working postfix installation and followed the guide posted in the question:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html

I installed stunnel on my ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get install stunnel4
```

Followed the guide here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-secure-tunnel.html

And the content of the final stunnel config file:

```
[smtp-tls-wrapper]
accept = 2525
client = yes
connect = email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:2587
delay = yes
cert = /etc/stunnel/mail.pem
protocol = smtp
```

**Important Notes:**

- The "protocol" config value is not mentioned in the docs, but it won't work without it
- Replace the "connect" value to match your region, but keep the port as 2587.
- As mentioned in the answer, you need to allow port 2587 from your google cloud console
- There is also port "2465" available for "TLS Wrapper" wich should also be possible to use with Google's Compute Engine.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the port 2587. That's all.
(I have tested via PHPmailer.)