# SES port is blocked in GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, google-cloud-platform

I have an application that is hosted on a GCP machine.
This application is supposed to send a mail via AWS SES service.

From what I've seen in GCP documentation, all default SMTP ports are blocked in GCP machines.

is it possible to unblock one of the ports or use another port for sending the mail?

Thank you,
Maya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 2525 is unblocked and all major vendors provide support for the 2525 smtp port.

Answer (score 2):

Use 2587 port instead of 587. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html#smtp-connect-starttls

Look [amazon SES on Google Cloud Computing instance VM using postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834047/amazon-ses-on-google-cloud-computing-instance-vm-using-postfix)